# iPhone in App purchase : Working but Not

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have added in App purchase functionality within my application. We have tested it successfully on iPhone (in sandbox mode). After successfully testing, we sent the application for final testing to tester situated at other country.

In strange case, the tester is not able to test in App purchase functionality. He is getting "Invalid Product Id" error. We are giving same build to tester which is working perfectly at our side. The whole application is working perfectly except in app purchase functionality.

If any guesses.

Thanks,
Vimal Jain.

Answer (score 8):

(I am copying it directly from http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/)

To save you the pain of exhaustively searching the web for the cause of your error, here is a checklist of everything I have stumbled across that can cause an invalid product ID. Make sure you can answer “Yes” to each of these questions:

```
* Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
* Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?
* Have you submitted (and optionally rejected) your application binary?
* Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
* Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?
* Have you configured your project to code sign using this new provisioning profile?
* Are you building for iPhone OS 3.0 or above?
* Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?
* Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect?
* Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect? (via Mark)
* Check that your device is not Jailbroken
```

If you answered “No” to any one of these questions, there’s your problem.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. 

I am able to successfully test the inApp purchase functionality in one device, but it's not working on other device. So the settings are correct. 

I want to know if there are some specific settings need to be done, on iPhone, to test inApp purchase (I know that user should logout from iTunes account from setting menu) or is it country specific ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add to your list "Check that your device is not Jailbroken" we have lost many hours trying to test IAP unsuccessfully on Jailbroken devices